# Extract date from text written timeslot

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Trying to extract the date from the written string `Thursday, Aug 25, 2022 2:00 PM-2:30 PM` which should result in a date value of `Thursday, Aug 25, 2022 2:00PM` (or any date & time format).

Assuming the string is located in cell G2, I tried `=TRIM(MID(G2,FIND(" ",G2),FIND(" ",G2,FIND(" ",G2)+1)-FIND(" ",G2)))` and all I get is: `Aug`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\b[A-z]{3} \d+. \d+\b")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: it still appears to be a string value, not a date/number value.

Comment: @WilliamToscano try: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\b[A-z]{3} \d+. \d+\b")*1`

Comment: Thank you, by any chance, is it possible to also include time of day? So "2:00PM - 2:30PM" would become "2:00PM" after the date.

Comment: @WilliamToscano sure. try: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\b[A-z]{3} \d+. \d+ \d+\:\d+ [AMP]{2}\b")*1` and don't forget to format it the way you want it (eg. including time) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMqy1.png

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to retain the AM/PM time format instead of converting it to military time?

Comment: @WilliamToscano yes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p81u.png